# R language optimize converting mpfr to gmp

Tags: r, gmp, mpfr

I wrote a function to convert, without loss of precision, a `mpfr` - class value to a `gmp  bigq` value. (This particular operation is not available in the R libraries Rmpfr and gmp, tho' there are functions to convert in the other direction). My code works but feels clumsy to me. Any suggestions to optimize?

```
mpfr2bigq <- function(x){
    xf <- formatMpfr(x)
    #count digits to right of dec point, if any
    xs <-unlist(strsplit(xf,''))
    thedot <- grep('[.]', xs)
    denom <- '1' # use this  if there's no decimal point
# as.bigz treats a leading '0' as a base indicator, so strip    
    num <- gsub('^0{1,}', '',xf ) # remove all to left of  dec point or 1st number
    if (length(thedot)){
        theexp <- length(xs[(thedot+1):length(xs)])
# 'num' has either integer or '.' as first char
        num <- gsub('[.]', '', num)
#have to repeat the zero removal in case  it was " 0.00xxx"
        num <- as.bigz(gsub('^0{1,}', '', num)) 
        denom <- as.bigz(10)^(theexp)   #casting order requires bigz(10)
    }
    return(invisible(as.bigq(num,denom)))
}
```

Comment: Well, as time passed, I wrote up and submitted a tiny package to CRAN: go2bigq . That function will convert pretty much anything (mpfr, numeric, char strings) to the equivalend bigq fraction.